# Android O showing not showing notification

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

In my app, the user needs to be reminded at a specific point in time - it's basically an alarm clock for a bus reminder.

It used to work pretty simple.

Calculate the time to show the event. Use `AlarmManager` to set alarm with a `PendingIntent` to trigger my alarm service by `PendingIntent.getService`.
Within my service, the only thing I need to do, is to create a `Notification` and display that using the `NotificationManager`.

That's it. Not more, not less.

But since Android O, my world gets crazy and shaken.

It simply does not work any more. I learn, I need to use `PendingIntent.getForegroundService`... okay. And that by that, I agree to call `Service.startForeground(notificationId, notification)`... otherwise I get killed within a few seconds.

Now... when I *do* call this method, no notification whatsoever is shown anymore. Simply nothing. But I do not get killed. I have not found out, whether I need to *also* call `NotificationManager.notify(...)`, but even if I do that, nothing gets shown at all.

If I *do not* call startForeground, my notification is displayed as always before - BUT I do get killed right after that.

Why on earth is this so damn complicated, unclear and straight stupid? What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Note: I have a notification channel. Of course. That is not the problem at all.

Comment: What did you setTimeoutAfter() to?

Comment: Nothing. What is that?